# Cron jobs in Azure: Automation, Scheduler, WebJobs or other solution?

Tags: azure, automation, cron, scheduler

Azure provides different ways to automate things, such as [Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/), Scheduler, Elastic Jobs and [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs). Comparison between WebJobs and Scheduler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462765/azure-webjobs-vs-scheduler). Now WebJobs supports crontab format. You can also set up crontab in Azure VM that is a solution to automatically execute a script. I cannot understand why Azure provides so many similarly-worded solutions. Are Automation, Scheduler and WebJobs all like unix crontab?

**How do the different scheduling tools compare in Azure to crontab?**

Answer (score 0):

Cron is just the format. As it's a stardard you can use it to configure the intervals for running your background task.

In terms of the multiple ways, I believe that it's related to your needs. For example, if you're using a Virtual Machine, you won't create a new app service and then use webjobs / azure functions. The same if you already have an app service, you won't use another way since you can use Azure Functions / Webjobs in the same app service plan.

To be honest I like this freedom to choose what best fits my needs.

Comment: If I am using AzureML, can I use WebJobs to execute the web service by some schedule? Yes? When would you do it such way and when would you do it other way? Is a web service an app?